# Cursor is crashing: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I don't know why my cursor is empty. I read other 4-5 questions which contain the same message but I couldn't fix my problem. What did I forget?

With this code I got the message: "Cursor is empty":

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String txt_edit_hw = edit_hw.getText().toString(); 
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("hw", txt_edit_hw);

        String test = "SELECT _id FROM tbl_homework where hw='"+ txt_edit_hw +"';";

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(test, null); 

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){

        String hw = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("hw"));


        doMessage(hw);
        db.update("tbl_homework", args, "_id=34", null);
        fillData();
        } else {
            doMessage("Cursor is empty");
        }
    }
```

With this code I got the crach... android Index 0 requested, with a size of 0:

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String txt_edit_hw = edit_hw.getText().toString(); 
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("hw", txt_edit_hw);

        String test = "SELECT _id FROM tbl_homework where hw='"+ txt_edit_hw +"';";

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(test, null); 

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        String hw = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("hw"));

        doMessage(hw);
        db.update("tbl_homework", args, "_id=34", null);
        fillData();
    }
```

Same error this way: It crashes at the String (I commented it)

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String txt_edit_hw = edit_hw.getText().toString(); 
        txt_edit_hw.trim();
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("hw", txt_edit_hw);

        String test = "SELECT _id FROM tbl_homework where hw='"+ txt_edit_hw +"';";

        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(test, null); 

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);
        mCursor.moveToFirst();

        /**It crashes here**/String hwl = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

        doMessage(hwl);
        db.update("tbl_homework", args, "_id=34", null);
        fillData();
    }

02-06 12:13:49.789: I/Process(6112): Sending signal. PID: 6112 SIG: 9
02-06 12:13:55.582: D/dalvikvm(6140): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 37K, 49% free 2785K/5379K, external 5211K/5218K, paused 23ms
02-06 12:13:58.785: D/AndroidRuntime(6140): Shutting down VM
02-06 12:13:58.785: W/dalvikvm(6140): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40091568)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at test.marco.notenha.homework$3.onClick(homework.java:227)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2486)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9130)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-06 12:13:58.796: E/AndroidRuntime(6140):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Table:
Rows: _id, hwdate, hw
Val : "34" , "05/02/12", "hy,xsdhagsah"

Comment: Your first approach is good. It seems that there is no any data present in database relating to your where condition. So you need to write query as String test = "SELECT * FROM tbl_homework where hw='"+ txt_edit_hw +"';"; Again if you didn't get result Check your database or use .trim() after edit_hw.getText().toString(). PS: Don't use getcount() there is no any need to do this.

Comment: Same error when I use txt_edit_hw.trim(); And I checked my database ;) There are some entries first one is with _id = 34.

Comment: Are you sure that your `where` clause is correct, that the selection is not empty?

Comment: I think it's right. I don't know what's wrong there...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply it says that your `Cursor` is not having any value and still you are trying to read from your `Cursor`. So, its always better to check the value of `cursor.getCount();`

```
Log.d("Count",String.valueOf(cursor.getCount())); 
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
// get values from cursor here
}
```

Comment: @Lalit Poptani Thanks for the answer but I don't like to know how to check for values in my Cursor. I like to know why is there nothing...
Added some code in question... Same error

Comment: To get the exact idea about your problem you should add the Logcat output to the question and also the table fields.

Comment: @LalitPoptani Table fields and LogCat output has been added. Thanks

Comment: While trying for what I suggested, what did you get for `Log.d("Count",cursor.getCount()+"");`? If you got 0 it means your cursor is not having value.

Comment: Yes Count is 0. How can I add values to my cursor? o_O

Comment: Okay... I tried it. But I can't figure out my mistake. Could you help me for writing the correct one? Thanks

Comment: just try to use a Static select query like `select _id from tbl_homework where hw='string_you_have_in_database'`, and the try to fetch.

Comment: dammit! I have to put a string into ''... ;D Thanks guys you're awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You select the `_id` column, yet you use `mCursor.getColumnIndex("hw")`. There is no column `hw` in your selection, only `_id`. `getColumnIndex()` returns `0`, you get corresponding error.

**UPD:** There is no need to use `getCount()`. Let me share some code snippets. Firstly, let's assume that we need only the first value from the cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = //query here
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // retrieve values from the cursor
}
```

If we need more than one value:

```
Cursor cursor = //query here
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // retrieve next set of values from the cursor
}
```

The initial position of the cursor is always `-1`, that's why the above code will work and process all entries.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that's right. But there are still the same error.
I posted some code in my question.